# admob_ads_sdk not present in android-sdk-linux/extras/google/

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services

I am trying to upgrade from maven 3.0.4 to 3.1.1. I use Ubuntu 12.04

When I try `mvn install -e`, I get the following error

```
/home/prasanna/library/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/admob_ads_sdk/source.properties not found
```

In my extras/google folder I see only

```
    analytics_sdk_v2            m2repository        play_licensing
    google_play_services        play_apk_expansion  webdriver
    google_play_services_froyo  play_billing
```

but not admob_ads_sdk

I tried to reinstall google play services by deleting it from sdk manager and reinstalling it. But it did not help. How can I fix this?

PS : I reinstalled my SDK 2 weeks ago and I wonder if I could fix this without going through the entire process again.

Comment: I think that's because AdMob is now part of the Google Play Services.

Comment: @dextor Have you got a work around for it?